# iOS App runs in Xcode build, but crashes in Test Flight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm building an app that runs fine on my iOS device when I build it in Xcode. I've uploaded it to TestFlight, but when I install it and run it on the same iOS device it crashes. It gets through the launchscreen, but crashes soon after. The only warning I have is this:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /.../FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts, missing required architecture arm64 in file /.../FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts (2 slices)
```

I've built this app before and run it through TestFlight, but now it's just not working. One of the changes that I made was that I updated the FacebookSDK, so maybe that's it? Hence the Bolts warning?

I'm sorry I'm not great at asking questions, but any help is hugely appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When you build for **Release**, make sure 'Build Active architecture' is set to NO, an that 'valid architectures' include all devices (*armv7 armv7s arm64*).

It seems the 'Bolt.framework' included with Facebook SDK wasn't built for arm64... Maybe someone at facebook fixed that ? ([or you can build it yourself :)](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS)

Comment: Thanks. Everything in the first paragraph is done, and I just decided to downgrade the FacebookSDK. I'm uploading now and I'll let you know

Comment: It didn't work. It did get rid of the Bolts warning, but the app still crashes upon load of the TestFlight version